# error undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

hi i added carrierwave gem to my project and followed instruction but i am getting this error- `undefined method 'avatar' for nil:NilClass`. can anyone knows why i am not able to upload and view the uploaded file?

```
1.gem install carrierwave
2.gem 'carrierwave', '~> 2.0'
3.rails generate uploader Avatar
4.rails g migration add_avatar_to_project_sites avatar:string
```

project_sites_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @project_sites = current_user.project_sites.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end
  def create
    @project_site = current_user.project_sites.build(project_site_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_site.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project_site, notice: 'Attendance uploaded successfully' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project_site }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project_site.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
def project_site_params
  params.require(:project_site).permit(:name, :file, :attendance_month, avatar: [])
end
```

project_site form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :avatar %>
  <%= form.file_field :avatar %>
</div>
```

model project_site.rb

```
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
```

avatar_uploader.rb

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

project_site index.html.erb

```
<%= image_tag @project_site.avatar.url %>
```

Comment: can you make sure that `@project_site` is not nil, because that's what the error says.

Comment: hey when i changes @project_site to @project_sites i am getting this error- undefined method `avatar' for #<ProjectSite::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x00007f0b14856f08>

Comment: You have to loop over `@project_sites` or you can do `@project_sites.first` if you only need to test if carrierwave is working.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do

```
<% @project_sites.each do |project_site| %>
  <% if project_site.avatar %>
    <%= image_tag project_site.avatar.url %>
  <% else %>
    No Image Present
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You can also give a default image to handle this.

Comment: That is because you do not have images for project_sites.

Comment: now getting error- Nil location provided. Can't build URI.

Comment: i have added image from form.html.erb

Comment: Your basics of `rails` are not clear and you should look to clear them here https://www.railstutorial.org .

Comment: i am using carrierwave gem for first time

Comment: check the updated answer, and your problem is not `carrierwave`.

Comment: bro passing instead of" avatar: [] " in controller i passed :avatar and it resolved the problem and  <%= image_tag project_site.avatar.url %> in view.

Comment: It's always good to mark the answer which helped you solve the problem. It helps in encouraging people to answer more and keeps the open questions count to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this `<%= image_tag(@user.avatar_url) if @user.avatar? %>`